# Visual Studio Code Компиляция многофайлового проекта

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Каким образом в **Visual Studio Code** можно организовать компиляцию многофайлового проекта. К примеру имеется 3 файла: `main.cpp`, `Sum.cpp`, `Sum.h`.

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sum.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");    

    cout << Sum(4, 5) << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Sum.cpp**

```
int Sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

**Sum.h**

```
int Sum(int a, int b);
```

Это компилирует таким образом `g++ main.cpp Sum.cpp -o main`

---

**Вопрос:** Как эту задачу делигировать непосредственно редактору. Просто я только могу провести компиляцию через консоль. Так же возможно коснуться вопроса компиляции с помощью Makefile(т.е привязка его для компиляции в редакторе), но важным является решение без его применения.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Данную задачу решил таким образом:**
1. Создал файл c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**", 
                "${workspaceFolder}/include" //дополнительно указал где мои heder файлы
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

2. В settings.json задал асоциацию по поиску:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.tpp": "cpp" //все tpp файлы
    },
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "cmd.exe"
}
```

3. В task.json создал две задачи, первая для сборки вторая для сборки и запуска:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {    //Каждая задача выделяется одним блоком
             "label": "Build C++ project",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "command": "make",
        },
        {  //<--- интересующая нас задача
            "label": "Build & run C++ project", //Имя задача
            "type": "shell",
            "group": {
                "kind": "test",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "command": "make", //Соответвенно сборка
            "args": [
                "run" //Аргумент для запуска
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Согласно моей основной задачи справиться без Makefile, то поля command и args будут следующими:

```
"command": "g++", 
            "args": [
                "-g", "-Wall", "main.cpp", "Sum.cpp", "-o", "main"
            ]
```

4. В launch.json добавил 2 поля:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Debug (gdb)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main", //указал место где лежит мой собранный исходник
            "preLaunchTask": "Build C++ project", //указал что перед запуском мы должны предварительно пересобрать проект
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```